# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'classes'

Tags: python, numpy

```
y_actual = X_train.classes[X_train.index_array]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-6fdd5283004e> in <module>()
----> 1 y_actual = X_train.classes[X_train.index_array]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'classes'
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question I guess :) Lines before the error are also needed along with the contents of your variables, i.e., [mcve]. You probably treat `X_train` as a pandas dataframe, but at some point it became a numpy array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of only the fragment code of the uploaded image, but
In the given situation, it seems that the training error occurred because the name of the class (label) was omitted during the training process.